# python pandas - unicode error

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to open an xls file with pandas python like this:

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile(path + filename)
```

but I get this error:
`pandas utf16 codec can't decode bytes in position...`

I tried to search for an answer but there is nothing that I found that could answer it.

any seuggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was the excel foramt.

I saved it again as an .xlsx instead of .xls and it worked.